# Pandas apply to data frame groupby

Tags: python, pandas

If I groupby (g object below) and then apply following function to first 1000 rows of df, it works. But if I apply it to entire df, I get this exception:

```
    def calc_load(x):
         ...:     x.sort('log_timestamp')
         ...:     x['time_stddev'] = x['time'].std()
         ...:     x['time_mean'] = x['time'].mean()
         ...:     return x
         ...:


    c=g.apply(calc_load)
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ........

    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-262-f2fe1f013907> in <module>()
    ----> 1 c=g.apply(calc_load)
       2215             tuple(map(int, [tot_items] + list(block_shape))),
    -> 2216             tuple(map(int, [len(ax) for ax in axes]))))
       2217
       2218

    ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 3943482), indices imply (10, 410450)
```

What's the cause here and how can I fix that?

**UPDATE:**

I'm reading this table from HDF5 store like this:

```
prob2
Out[374]:
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: /tmp/test2.h5
/mytable            frame_table  (typ->appendable,nrows->410450,ncols->8,indexers->[index])

a=prob2.mytable

a
Out[376]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 410450 entries, 0 to 9999
Data columns (total 8 columns):
args             410450  non-null values
host             410450  non-null values
kwargs           410450  non-null values
log_timestamp    410450  non-null values
operation        410450  non-null values
slot             410450  non-null values
status           410450  non-null values
time             410450  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(5)
```

If I do round-trip to CSV like below, the exception does NOT happen:

```
a.to_csv('/tmp/test2.csv')

b=pd.read_csv('/tmp/test2.csv')

b
Out[379]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 410450 entries, 0 to 410449
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Unnamed: 0       410450  non-null values
args             410450  non-null values
host             410450  non-null values
kwargs           410450  non-null values
log_timestamp    410450  non-null values
operation        410450  non-null values
slot             410450  non-null values
status           410450  non-null values
time             410450  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(3), object(5)

bg = b.groupby(['host','operation'])

bg.apply(calc_load)
Out[381]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 410450 entries, 0 to 410449
Data columns (total 11 columns):
Unnamed: 0       410450  non-null values
args             410450  non-null values
host             410450  non-null values
kwargs           410450  non-null values
log_timestamp    410450  non-null values
operation        410450  non-null values
slot             410450  non-null values
status           410450  non-null values
time             410450  non-null values
time_stddev      410371  non-null values
time_mean        410450  non-null values
dtypes: float64(3), int64(3), object(5)
```

The dataframes before roundtrip (a) and after roundtrip(b) look similar but they're not identical!

```
a
Out[386]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 410450 entries, 0 to 9999
Data columns (total 8 columns):
args             410450  non-null values
host             410450  non-null values
kwargs           410450  non-null values
log_timestamp    410450  non-null values
operation        410450  non-null values
slot             410450  non-null values
status           410450  non-null values
time             410450  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(5)



b
Out[387]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 410450 entries, 0 to 410449
Data columns (total 9 columns):
Unnamed: 0       410450  non-null values
args             410450  non-null values
host             410450  non-null values
kwargs           410450  non-null values
log_timestamp    410450  non-null values
operation        410450  non-null values
slot             410450  non-null values
status           410450  non-null values
time             410450  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), int64(3), object(5)
```

Erm, what's going on here?

Comment: you need to supply a working example, maybe use dropbox to supply your frame (or create an example to show the error)

Comment: @Jeff, it's in the UPDATE. And thanks a million times for all your assistance!!

Comment: can u do a ``df.head()`` so can see the values. looks like you have a string-like column (marked) as object dtype. Object dtypes should only be for string-like. You may need to do some conversions (before you even put it in HDF5). where does the data come from before that step?

Comment: can u post your hdf5 on dropbox?

Comment: Here's Dataframe: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf053hk1vn10iep/problem_df2.h5

Here's what triggers that exception:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/roo7jyfkngwt57i/value_error_on_df.py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by host/operation, you have many duplicates. This is why the first 1000 rows prob worked but the entire set does not.

First reset the index, then group and apply. You can recover your original index by then setting the index at the end. The reset index is turned into a column called 'index' (which set_index then drops).

This is a fairly common pattern actually. I think a more helpful error message may be in order, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5758). As I am not sure groupby should auto-fix this (it could). As this could be user error OR intent.

```
In [26]: df = d.reset_index().groupby(['host','operation']).apply(calc_load).set_index('index')

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
      args            host kwargs        log_timestamp             operation      slot  status      time  time_stddev  time_mean
index                                                                                                                           
0       []   yy3.segm1.org     {}  1385984306000000000      x_gWidgboxParams    a12yy3    -101  0.000477     0.061657   0.003226
1       []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984306000000000         x_initWidgbox   a11yy14       1  0.004177     0.035759   0.005816
10      []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984307000000000             gSettings   a13yy32    -101  0.009686     0.245170   0.070137
100     []  yy19.segm1.org     {}  1385984308000000000  notifyTestsDelivered   a16yy19       1  0.000766     0.002825   0.000964
1000    []   yy7.segm1.org     {}  1385984320000000000           addWidging2    a12yy7       1  0.002576     0.008525   0.004122
10000   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000           addWidging2   a13yy14       1  0.001317     0.009431   0.003910
10001   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               gxyzinf   a13yy14    -101  0.000542     0.001861   0.001074
10002   []  yy20.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               x_gbinf  I502yy20    -101  0.000522     0.001043   0.000743
10003   []  yy20.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000       setFlagsOneWidg  I502yy20       1  0.001660     0.005404   0.002910
10004   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000  notifyTestsDelivered   a13yy14       1  0.000551     0.002877   0.001156
10005   []  yy20.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               gxyzinf  I502yy20    -101  0.000521     0.000802   0.000813
10006   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000           addWidging2   a13yy14       1  0.001256     0.009431   0.003910
10007   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               gxyzinf   a13yy14    -101  0.000414     0.001861   0.001074
10008   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000           addWidging2   a13yy14       1  0.001222     0.009431   0.003910
10009   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               gxyzinf   a13yy14    -101  0.000475     0.001861   0.001074
1001    []   yy7.segm1.org     {}  1385984320000000000               gxyzinf    a12yy7    -101  0.000783     0.003059   0.001004
10010   []  yy14.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000         x_initWidgbox   a12yy14       1  0.002764     0.035759   0.005816
10011   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000         x_initWidgbox   a15yy32       1  0.057966     0.334923   0.147668
10012   []   yy3.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000             gSettings    a11yy3    -101  0.006519     0.163707   0.017649
10013   []  yy30.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000                gtfull   a13yy30    -101  0.003648     0.116366   0.014088
10014   []   yy6.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               x_gbinf    a16yy6    -101  0.000621     0.005796   0.001139
10015   []  yy34.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000                gtfull   a14yy34    -101  0.002031     0.015581   0.007747
10016   []  yy34.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               x_gbinf   a14yy34    -101  0.000546     0.002596   0.001899
10017   []  yy34.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000       setFlagsOneWidg   a14yy34       1  0.001358     0.003515   0.005866
10018   []  yy34.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000               gxyzinf   a14yy34    -101  0.000486     0.004446   0.002018
10019   []  yy25.segm1.org     {}  1385984461000000000                gtfull   a13yy25    -101  0.002029     0.001793   0.002355
1002    []   yy7.segm1.org     {}  1385984320000000000  notifyTestsDelivered    a12yy7       1  0.000847     0.003748   0.001081
10020   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000             gFolderId   a15yy32    -101  0.018326     0.187434   0.058200
10021   []  yy25.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               x_gbinf   a13yy25    -101  0.000589     0.001716   0.000830
10022   []  yy25.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000            updateWidg   a13yy25       1  0.003058     0.004660   0.003973
10023   []  yy25.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000            clearElems   a13yy25       1  0.000661     0.004893   0.001687
10024   []  yy10.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000                gtfull   a18yy10    -101  0.002779     0.069679   0.007495
10025   []  yy13.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000                gtfull   a11yy13    -101  0.001978     0.124069   0.012524
10026   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               x_gbinf   a14yy32    -101  0.018674     0.190657   0.058083
10027   []  yy10.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               x_gbinf   a18yy10    -101  0.000874     0.007170   0.001606
10028   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               gWidgId   a14yy32       1  0.014523     1.518315   0.559983
10029   []  yy13.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               x_gbinf   a11yy13    -101  0.000577     0.008605   0.001130
1003    []   yy7.segm1.org     {}  1385984320000000000      x_gWidgboxParams    a12yy7    -101  0.000933     0.001084   0.001442
10030   []  yy13.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000       setFlagsOneWidg   a11yy13       1  0.001611     0.011409   0.004093
10031   []  yy13.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               gxyzinf   a11yy13    -101  0.000575     0.053991   0.003044
10032   []  yy39.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000                gtfull   a13yy39    -101  0.002005     0.034577   0.003504
10033   []  yy39.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               x_gbinf   a13yy39    -101  0.000539     0.001371   0.000931
10034   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000           addWidging2   a15yy32       1  0.122369     1.414068   0.441565
10035   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000           moveOneWidg   a12yy32       1  0.468481     1.303089   0.665778
10036   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               gxyzinf   a15yy32    -101  0.018006     0.155379   0.040389
10037   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000  notifyTestsDelivered   a15yy32       1  0.006874     0.129650   0.032741
10038   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               gxyzinf   a12yy32    -101  0.016607     0.155379   0.040389
10039   []  yy39.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000            updateWidg   a13yy39       1  0.003879     0.005466   0.006465
1004    []  yy34.segm1.org     {}  1385984320000000000                gtfull   a11yy34    -101  0.003681     0.015581   0.007747
10040   []  yy39.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000                SELECT   a13yy39  217831  0.000423     0.000126   0.000551
10041   []  yy39.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000            clearElems   a13yy39       1  0.000705     0.002367   0.001356
10042   []   yy3.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000           moveOneWidg    a15yy3       1  0.002660     0.027428   0.009078
10043   []   yy3.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               gxyzinf    a15yy3    -101  0.000436     0.041627   0.001913
10044   []  yy39.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000             gSettings   a11yy39    -101  0.002237     0.007467   0.002679
10045   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000             gSettings   a15yy32    -101  0.012113     0.245170   0.070137
10046   []  yy32.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000      x_gWidgboxParams   a15yy32    -101  0.030427     0.143941   0.050055
10047   []  yy13.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000           moveOneWidg   a12yy13       1  0.003796     0.117085   0.017910
10048   []  yy13.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000               gxyzinf   a12yy13    -101  0.000521     0.053991   0.003044
10049   []  yy30.segm1.org     {}  1385984462000000000      x_gWidgboxParams   a13yy30    -101  0.002451     0.051829   0.003644
1005    []  yy12.segm1.org     {}  1385984320000000000                gtfull   a15yy12    -101  0.003428     0.005479   0.003063
       ...             ...    ...                  ...                   ...       ...     ...       ...          ...        ...

[410450 rows x 10 columns]
```